# send data to running instance

Tags: java, class, methods, instance

Hello I am creating software which allow files to be uploaded, my software has a chat client which will create a instance of a file uploader class, this file uploader class will take the file from the file chooser, convert it to byte and upload it to the sql database. so essentially I have a main chat client which contains a text area for chat to be show in. I have main chat windows which displays contacts. when the user double clicks on a contact the chat client opens up:

```
private void jList1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
        String userID = lbluserID.getText();
        String selectedContact = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
        ChatClient chatClientObject = new ChatClient(selectedContact, userID);  
        ChatClient.runchatClient(selectedContact, userID);

    }
}
```

within this chat client I have placed a button which allows the selection of the file. the dbconnect class will upload the file to the server, once this is done I need a message to appear in the chat client text area displaying that the file has been uploaded. I have tried to make a instance of the chat client in the dbconnect class and then call a method to output the message how ever this gives me errors. what I really want to do is allow my program to open the chat client for the contact the user clicks on and also be able to return the message to the same chat client instead of creating a new instance.

I hope my question is clear as it is pretty hard to explain.... for example, If i click on "Ben" in the main client a chat client will open for "ben" this chat client contains a text area. when i have finished uploading the file which is done by the dbconnect class I want the string message "file sent" to be returned to the chat I have open with "ben".

Comment: I think basically my question is how can I call a method in a running instance of a class from another class instead of creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

you said 'I have tried to make a instance of the chat client in the dbconnect class and then call a method to output the message how ever this gives me errors.'

Don't create new instance of client to send file completion message, you need to be use the same instance that was created at the time of client instantiated. So that at the time of client instantiated 1st time you need to hold that reference in global variable. And call method using this instance to display message.

It could help you.

Comment: everytime the user doubles clicks on a contact from their contact list in the main client a instance of the chat client is created, so there could be many instances of the chat client open. how would i use globals to allow these instances to be accessed from other classes? im sorry im so puzzled.